# withContext(Dispatchers.IO) how to use for room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In our app there are so many queries and now we are using ROOM , I want to confirm that what is proper way to use Coroutine before we was using like this

In Dao

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM VISITS")
    suspend fun getAllVisits(): List<Visits>
```

And we are getting like this

```
fun getAll(visit: Visits?) = runBlocking {
        Log.i(TAG, "addOrUpdateRecord")
        try {

val list = ArrayList<Visits>()
                list.addAll(async {
                    visitsDao.getAllVisits()
                }.await())

}
```

But in some articale i have read that runblocking is for only testing not production please guide me proper way Thank you

Comment: You can use either launch {} or withContext(io) {}  <- this return type

Comment: I am unable to use withcontext  without runblocker any idea

Comment: you need to create class that extend ViewModel() and just implement @Glenn Sandoval . read more here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a coroutine scope to launch a coroutine you have either `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` ready to use according to your needs.

Inside an Activity:

```
fun myMethod() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val list = visitsDao.getAllVisits()
        //Do something with list here
            ...
    }
}
```

Inside a Fragment:

```
fun myMethod() {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        val list = visitsDao.getAllVisits()
        //Do something with list here
            ...
    }
}
```

Inside a ViewModel:

```
fun myMethod() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val list = visitsDao.getAllVisits()
        //Do something with list here
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside a regular class:

```
class MyPresenter: CoroutineScope {
    private val myJob = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Default + myJob
    
    ...

    fun myMethod() {
        launch {
            val list = visitsDao.getAllVisits()
            //Do something with list here
            ...
        }
    }
    
    ...

    //Call clear when required
    fun clear() {
        this.myJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Our design pattern is MVP still I can use this method?

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain You can implement `CoroutineScope` in your Presenter like this: `class MyPresenter: CoroutineScope by MainScope(){ ... }` . Use the right Dispatcher according to your needs or build its `CoroutineContext` by yourself without delegation. Just be careful to cancel its scope properly.

Comment: if I implement CoroutineScope like you are doing in presenter in my tableHelperClass and use launch(Dispatchers.IO) in run my queries is it good practice?

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain If you add `suspend` keyword to your DAO method you don't have to worry about the dispatcher that makes the call. Room will execute the query on a background thread.

Comment: so I just need to use launch ? and this is the correct way which I Mention?

Comment: and how to cancel running long query , if user backpress and moved to another activity how to cancel running query ?

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain `launch` will run on the `coroutineContext`'s dispatcher. Just make sure to build the CoroutineContext with the right dispatcher and when you need to change the dispatcher inside a function then you can use `withContext`. In your case just marking a DAO method as suspending is enough. Room will execute the query on a background thread as I mentioned.

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain To cancel the execution just call `cancel` on the Job or on the CoroutineScope. Look at the `clear` method I made.

Comment: in presenter we not using myJob  but just using for cancel?

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain One of the CoroutineContext's elements is a Job. Every call to `launch` returns a Job. Use that Job to `cancel` the coroutine. In `MyPresenter` I create a Job which I use to build the CoroutineContext and I use that Job to cancel everything taking advantage of the structured concurrency.

Comment: I am doing the same thing and using this.myjob.cancel but job is not canceling

Comment: @bakhtiyarhussain Make coroutines cooperative with cancellation. This might help you understand how coroutines work: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html

Comment: please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914896/use-runblocking-for-room-queries

Comment: Thank You So Much @Glenn Sandoval You Solved my problem

Comment: @GlennSandoval what about DataStore? It seems that we have to update data we need to specify Default or IO coroutine dispatcher manually.

Comment: @user924 "DataStore saves the preferences in a file and performs all data operations on `Dispatchers.IO` unless specified otherwise". That's a quote taken from [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/09/prefer-storing-data-with-jetpack.html) where they compare SharedPreferences and DataStore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
GlobalScope.launch { 
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                // your query
            }
        }
```

Comment: based on @Chirag Rayani answers, if you're using viewModel, you can use viewModelScope.launch{ withContext(dispatchers.IO)} and combine it with livedata.postValue()

Comment: if you use viewModelScope and lets say you are updating the single row in db and before row gets updated you switch to another activity then you might get an exception or data might not update in db. so i think its better to use GlobalScope @Yehezkiel L

Comment: while the viewModel is attach to the activity or fragment lifecycle, it still okay cmiiw

Comment: GlobalScope is not a good practice GlobalScope never kill automatically even if we close the app that's why I am not using this

Comment: you don't use GlobalScope on Android, because Activity/Fragment/ViewModel/Service have their own scope

Answer (score 1):

In Viewmodel :

```kotlin
viewmodelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
  visitsDao.getAllVisits()
}
```

OR another suspend function

```kotlin
suspend fun addAll() {
    visitsDao.getAllVisits().run{
     ArrayList<Visits>().addAll(this)

   }
}
```

EvenMore, just use flow, and you can do with livedata builder/map/asLiveData etc.

Comment: have a look plz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66914896/can-we-use-runblocking-with-coroutine-for-room-queries-in-production#

Comment: Yeah, I 've seen that. And here is my result ,runblocking is not recommended. Check [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#bridging-blocking-and-non-blocking-worlds).  " The main thread invoking runBlocking blocks until the coroutine inside runBlocking completes."    If you don't have a ViewModel , just use MainScope(), which could be cancelled when view is destroyted. And you could create your own, just use the  **SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main** .

Comment: By the way, I was used to using **MainScope** before Google creating viewModelScope and lifecycleScope. Check [kotlinx.coroutines/-main-scope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-main-scope.html)