# can we use runblocking with coroutine for room queries in production?

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In our product we are using MVP pattern and in Room examples and after long searching I am getting all example with MVVM but now I found this way to run my Room queries using runblocking everything working smoothly I want to know that is this good way to use coroutines, I have heard that runblocking is not recommended for production

```
@Query("""SELECT V.* FROM VISITS AS V LEFT JOIN ORDERS AS O ON O.visitId = V.visitId 
        WHERE V.visitComplete = 1 AND V.visitId = :visitId AND (V.shopClosed = 1 OR O.orderTotal > 0)""")
suspend fun getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId: Int): Visits
```

And in my table Helper I am getting result like this

```
fun getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId: Int): Visits? = runBlocking {

    var data: Visits? = null
    try {
        data = async {
            visitsDao.getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId)
        }.await()
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        CustomMethods.errorLog(e, "getCompletedVisitByVisitId", ErrorLog.TYPE_ERROR, ErrorLog.APPLICATION_ERROR, context)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    data
}

override fun getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId: Int): Visits? {
        return visitsTableHelper!!.getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId)
    }
```

Comment: Where is `getCompletedVisitByVisitId` getting called?

Comment: code added , its calling in model class then presenter

Comment: What is what exactly? Where does the chain of calls start? Does it start in your activity or fragment? Do you need to wait for the result or you're applying the observer pattern?

Comment: I need result in activity to perform more task and yes need to wait for the result may be some time it take time and coroutine done that's I am using run blocking for safe side

Comment: If the chain of calls starts in your Activity and you're not applying observer pattern then use `lifecycleScope` in your Activity to launch the coroutine. Then make all the methods in the chain suspendable returning exactly what they receive from Room.

Comment: if we update UI in presenter still we need to use lifecycleScope, but in presenter we don't have lifecyclerScope .

Comment: Implement CoroutineScope interface in Presenter and build its CoroutineContext. Then just call `launch` to start a coroutine.

Comment: ok i have added interface in presenter with job like this   get() = Dispatchers.Default + myJob and called launch like this to get data launch {
                    obStoresListFromPJP = mModel!!.getPJPBStoresByStoreNameAndCurrentDate(searchText!!, TimeDateHelper.getDateOnly())
                }

Comment: Thank You So Much @Glenn Sandoval You Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

androidx.lifecycle package provides extension function for lifecycle owners (activity,fragment,viewmodel etc). So, it would be convenient to to use the `lifecycleScope.launch` for MVP pattern. By this way your coroutine jobs will automatically get canceled when the lifecycle owner is not in its active state.

So, you code can be life below:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    .....
    lifecycleScope.launch {
       try {
          val visits = getCompletedVisitByVisitId(someNumber)
          // do something with your data
       } catch (e: Exception) {
          //handle exception 
       }
    }
}
suspend fun getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId: Int): Visits? {

    var data: Visits? = null
    try {
        data = visitsDao.getCompletedVisitByVisitId(visitId)
    } catch (e: SQLException) {
        CustomMethods.errorLog(e, "getCompletedVisitByVisitId", ErrorLog.TYPE_ERROR, ErrorLog.APPLICATION_ERROR, context)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    data
}
```

Also import the dependencies:

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Comment: for using lifecycleScope we have to change multiple classes for using lifecycleScope, because i can't use lifecycleScope in my tablehelperClass

Comment: Then inside lifecycleScope you can call necessary methods from the instance of your TableHelper class

Comment: so i need to use lifecycle with runblocker?